# Count and loop through checked checkboxes

Tags: php, html

I have these checkboxes in a form:

```
<form action="/nextpage.php" method="post>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" hidden></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="line[]"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="line[]"></td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="line[]"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In `nextpage.php` I have this:

```
<?php

$line = $_POST['line'];
echo count($line);

?>
```

But it does not return the number of checked checkboxes. I want to create a loop for each checked box. How can I do this?

Comment: Your form needs a `method` to be `POST`. Use error reporting and PHP will tell you these issues. Also `<input type="checkbox" hidden>` is likely an issue.

Comment: foreach($line as $ln)

Comment: @user3783243 Already have that, forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: "But it does not return the number of checked checkboxes" What browser are you using? What does `count($line)` return? And what does `var_dump($line)` give you?

Comment: An example that you may find useful: Note that the 'value' attribute needs to be set. [Handling checkbox in a PHP form processor](https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-checkbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form action="#" method="post">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type='checbox' hidden></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name='veri[]' value="data1"></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="veri[]" value="data2"></td>
         </tr>
          <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="veri[]" value="data3"></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php


$lines = isset($_POST['veri']) ? $_POST['veri'] : null; 

print_r($lines);
?>
```

Comment: Answer should have an explanation of what was changed and why.